# Display arabic word in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeignter,  in  my view page

Method 1: 
views/show.php

```
echo @html_entity_decode("﷼", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

Html Output

```
﷼
```

This works fine.

BUT.

Method 2:
In config/constants.php, I have defined constant value for the arabic word like this:

```
define('ARABIC_WORD', '﷼');
```

and in my view page, views/show.php

```
echo @html_entity_decode(ARABIC_WORD, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

Html output:

```
?
```

I need to work for second option (method 2), so that I can define the values. Please anyone out there to help me in this to let me know what I have made mistake and if any new suggestions for this.

Comment: is `constants.php` stored as utf-8?

Comment: It is a codeigniter's constants.php file (file path application/config/constants.php)

Comment: my view page is in utf-8 though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your constant definition from

```
define(ARABIC_WORD, '﷼');
```

to

```
define('ARABIC_WORD', '﷼');
```

EDIT:

You are not storing your file as UTF-8 encoding and it is changed to "?". I have checked it, When I use `ANSI` encoding, it is changed to `?`. Your text editor should have an option called encoding somewhere. Change the encoding to `UTF-8` and then paste/write the line again and save it.

Comment: thanks for correction in defining constant. But its not the solution i am looking at.

Comment: Is your Config setting alright. charset should be this `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: When you are editing your constant.php, check whether your editor encoding is set to `UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks buddy. Its absolutely correct answer. I have been using PHPDesigner 7 IDE which won't warn me for encoding option and my files were not supporting UTF-8. I changed coding on Dreamweaver, while I saved file, it warned me. Now the things are cleared. Thank you @sakibmoon.